# How to pass object with a back key press

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have got a form with some elements. If I click on one of them, I move to the other page where I want to select any object. With confirmation I want to go back to the form where I want to work with selected object.

I know I can go back for example with this

```
                if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                {
                    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
```

but I don't know how to pass object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

Create a member to save the selected object which can then be accessed from the previous page, e.g.:

```
public MyObjectType SelectedItem { get; private set; }
```

(It could bet on an item selected event or by a binding or when back is pressed.)